# How to show window switch bar at the bottom like Microsoft Windows?

Tags: window

Besides disable launcher, is there any other way to do this?

I am using 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Unity can only show its bar on the left-hand side of the screen at the moment. If this worries you a lot, you can:

- try installing some dock, such as Docky, AWN or CairoDock. See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/you-choose-the-best-dock-for-ubuntu-poll/ for an overview.
- Use "Gnome classic" session, which does have a panel at the bottom though it's not quite similar to Windows.
- Install "kubuntu-desktop" and use a KDE session, which may be closer to Windows experience.

Though I admit the last two options feel like a bit on an overkill for just moving the panel to the bottom :)

Comment: I vote for using Docky - it is easy configurable and once you start using it you can simply hide/ignore the other panel managers.

Answer (score 1):

The Unity launcher can not (yet) be moved.

Using Gnome Panel (select Ubuntu Classic from the session menu when you login) you can add GnoMenu and DockbarX for something that resembles Windows 7 very much and it can be placed at the bottom of the screen.

If you like that setup and want to keep it, then you should have a look at Xfce, which does support Gnome Panel applets using xfapplet. But Gnome panel is deprecated and will go away with 11.10 never to return. It's based on really ancient technologies that should've been put to sleep years ago.

Both Gnome Panel and Xfce4-Panel can be run with Unity, though, meaning that you can have both a Windows-type dock and the more intelligent Unity at the same time. :)